# going to specific path in scala using scala.sys.process

Tags: scala, unix, deployment, playframework-2.2

I have to go to the path of an application to deploy it, I tried using `scala.sys.process` and did `"cd /home/path/somepath" !`

It is throwing an exception, Can anyone guide me how I can go to the directory, I cannot deploy it using absolute path because of the dependency the run file has.

Thanks in advance

Comment: All that would do (if it worked at all)  is changing the current directory of the created process, which then exits. Net effect, nothing. It's not clear what you're trying to do once you've changed the working directory - can you add more detail?

Comment: yes sure, I have to kill a process and then start it again, So this application has some dependencies on its libs, So I need to to the application and then only I can start it again, so I need go to the path of the application and then run it. Can you suggest how I can do it, since cd is not working programmatically.                                                                                                Thanks in advance.

Comment: Execute a shell script. In that script, cd to the right place, and start the app.

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but I wanted to do it from my application itself, currently am doing it from the shell script only, wanted to know if there was a neater way to do it programatically

Comment: Changing the working directory of the scala app seems the wrong approach. Use the shell script

Comment: Thanks will use that approach..

Answer (score 3):

Although this question is a couple of years old, it's a good question.

To use scala.sys.process to execute something from a specific working directory, pass the required directory as a parameter to ProcessBuilder, as in this working example:

```
import scala.sys.process._
val scriptPath = "/home/path/myShellScript.sh"
val command = Seq("/bin/bash","-c",scriptPath)
val proc = Process(command,new java.io.File("."))
var output = Vector.empty[String]
val exitValue = proc ! ProcessLogger (
(out) => if( out.trim.length > 0 )
  output +:= out.trim,
(err) =>
  System.err.printf("e:%s\n",err) // can be quite noisy!
)
printf("exit value: %d\n",exitValue)
printf("output[%s]\n",output.mkString("\n"))
```

If the goal instead is to insure that the environment of the caller defaults to a specific working directory, that can be accomplished by setting the required working directory before launching the jvm.